# Implementing a user defined Exception in a shapes program for resizing the frame

Tags: java, exception, resize, dimension, jslider

I'm making a program that draws shapes. Once you click on a shape in a menu, it draws the shape below according to the value in a jSlider.

I'm trying to create an exception so that when the user tries to resize the frame to smaller than the drawn shape on the DrawPanel.

To do this I want to create an if-statement so if the width or height of the frame is smaller than the x-y positions plus the value of the slider, it will throw an exception.

DrawShape:

```
package ShapesProgram;
//adding the imports
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 *
 * @
 */
public class DrawShape extends JPanel {

//Declaring variables 
private boolean isCircle;
private boolean isSquare;
private boolean isTriangle;
private int xPosition = 50;
private int yPosition = 50;
MyFrame shapeFrame;
int length;

//making the frame
public DrawShape(MyFrame f) {
    shapeFrame = f;
    initComponents();
    isCircle = false;
    isSquare = false;
    isTriangle = false;
    this.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    repaint();
}

public void setLength(int length) {
    this.length = length;
}

//setting the shapes to false
public void setIsCircle(boolean isCircle) {
    this.isCircle = isCircle;
    this.isSquare = false;
    this.isTriangle = false;

}

public void setIsSquare(boolean isSquare) {
    this.isSquare = isSquare;
    this.isCircle = false;
    this.isTriangle = false;
}

public void setIsTriangle(boolean isTriangle) {
    this.isTriangle = isTriangle;
    this.isSquare = false;
    this.isCircle = false;
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    super.paintComponent(g);

    if (isSquare == true) {
        // draw a Square
        g2.drawRect(xPosition, yPosition, length, length);
        repaint();
    } else if (isCircle == true) {

        // draw a Circle
        g2.drawOval(xPosition, yPosition, length, length);
        repaint();
    } else if (isTriangle == true) {

        // draw a Trianlge
        int[] xPoints = new int[3];
        int[] yPoints = new int[3];
        xPoints[0] = xPosition;
        xPoints[1] = xPoints[0];
        xPoints[2] = xPoints[1] + length;
        yPoints[0] = yPosition;
        yPoints[1] = yPoints[0] + length;
        yPoints[2] = yPoints[1];
        g2.drawPolyline(xPoints, yPoints, xPoints.length);
        g2.drawLine(xPoints[0], yPoints[0], xPoints[2], yPoints[2]);

        repaint();
    }

}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
}// </editor-fold>                        
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

MyControlPanel:

```
package ShapesProgram;
//adding the imports
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

/**
*
* @
*/
public class MyControlPanel extends JPanel {

//making a new slider
private ChangeListener sliderAction = new MyChangeAction();
JSlider thejSlider = new JSlider(0, 100);
//creating the labels for Boundary Length, Slider and Area
JLabel lblLenght = new JLabel("Boundary Length");
JLabel lblSlider = new JLabel("Slider");
JLabel lblArea = new JLabel("Area");
//creating the textFields for the Area and Boundary Lengrth
JTextField txtArea = new JTextField(8);
JTextField txtBLength = new JTextField(8);
MyFrame MyControlPanelFrame;
//Constraints required for GridBagLayout
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

public MyControlPanel(MyFrame f) {

    MyControlPanelFrame = f;
    initComponents();

    //setting background color and layout for the frame
    this.setBackground(Color.gray);
    this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());


    //setting up slider and adding it to the frame 
    thejSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
    thejSlider.setPaintLabels(true);
    thejSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
    gbc.gridx = 14;
    gbc.gridy = 11;
    this.add(thejSlider, gbc);

    //addig the label for the slider to the frame
    this.add(lblSlider, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 4;
    gbc.gridy = 11;

    //adding the label for the area to the frame
    this.add(lblArea, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 10;
    gbc.gridy = 11;

    //adding the textField for area to the frame
    this.add(txtArea, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.gridy = 10;
    gbc.gridwidth = 4;

    //adding the label for boundary length to the frame
    this.add(lblLenght, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 10;
    gbc.gridy = 10;

    //adding the textField for boundary length to the frame
    this.add(txtBLength, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 14;
    gbc.gridy = 10;


    linkEventHandler();


}
//creating the event handler for the slider action

public void linkEventHandler() {
    thejSlider.addChangeListener(sliderAction);

}

class MyChangeAction implements ChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {

        //obtain jslider value
        int currentValue = thejSlider.getValue();
        //passing the value of the slider to the draw panel
        MyControlPanelFrame.getDrawPanel().setLength(currentValue);
        //setting the format for the numbers
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.0");


        //obtain the shape
        //calculate Area
        double x = MyControlPanelFrame.getMyShape().computeArea(currentValue);
        //display area
        txtArea.setText(df.format(x));

        //obtain the shape
        //calculate boundary length
        double y = MyControlPanelFrame.getMyShape().computeBLength(currentValue);
        //display boundary length
        txtBLength.setText(df.format(y));



        //repaint the shape
        MyControlPanelFrame.getDrawPanel().repaint();



    }

}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
}// </editor-fold>                        
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

MyFrame:

```
package ShapesProgram;
//adding the imports
import MyShape.Circle;
import MyShape.MyShape;
import MyShape.Square;
import MyShape.Triangle;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

/**
*
* @
*/
public final class MyFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

MyShape myShape = new MyShape();

//creating a new JMenuBar
JMenuBar jMenuBar1 = new JMenuBar();
JMenu shape = new JMenu("Shape");

//creating new JMenuItems dor the shapes
JMenuItem circle = new JMenuItem("Circle");
JMenuItem square = new JMenuItem("Square");
JMenuItem triangle = new JMenuItem("Triangle");

MyControlPanel panel1 = new MyControlPanel(this);
DrawShape drawPanel = new DrawShape(this);

//Creates new form MyFrame
public MyFrame() {

    //setting the size, title and minimum size of the frame
    this.setSize(400, 400);
    this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
    this.setTitle("Shapes Program");

    initComponents();
    linkListeners();

    //setting the layout for the frame
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    //adding the components to the frame
    shape.add(square);
    shape.add(circle);
    shape.add(triangle);
    jMenuBar1.add(shape);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    //adding the panels to the frame 
    this.add(panel1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    this.add(drawPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}



//creating a new action listener for the shapes
public void linkListeners() {
    MyActionListener l = new MyActionListener();
    circle.addActionListener(l);
    square.addActionListener(l);
    triangle.addActionListener(l);

}

class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


        Object obj = e.getSource();

        //when square is selected, it is set to visable 
        //and outputs "Square Selected
        if ((JMenuItem) obj == square) {
            myShape = new Square();
            drawPanel.setIsSquare(true);
            System.out.println("Square Selected");

            //when circle is selected, it is set to visable 
            //and outputs "Circle Selected
        } else if ((JMenuItem) obj == circle) {
            myShape = new Circle();
            drawPanel.setIsCircle(true);
            System.out.println("Circle Selected");

            } 

            //when triangle is selected, it is set to visable 
            //and outputs "Triangle Selected
          else if ((JMenuItem) obj == triangle) {
            myShape = new Triangle();
            drawPanel.setIsTriangle(true);
            System.out.println("Triangle Selected");

        }
    }
}

public DrawShape getDrawPanel() {
    return drawPanel;

}

public MyShape getMyShape() {
    return myShape;
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code        (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look    and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MyFrame().setVisible(true);
            DecimalFormat oneDigit = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0");

        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

MyFrame:

```
package ShapesProgram;
//adding the imports
import MyShape.Circle;
import MyShape.MyShape;
import MyShape.Square;
import MyShape.Triangle;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

/**
*
* @
*/
public final class MyFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

MyShape myShape = new MyShape();

//creating a new JMenuBar
JMenuBar jMenuBar1 = new JMenuBar();
JMenu shape = new JMenu("Shape");

//creating new JMenuItems dor the shapes
JMenuItem circle = new JMenuItem("Circle");
JMenuItem square = new JMenuItem("Square");
JMenuItem triangle = new JMenuItem("Triangle");

MyControlPanel panel1 = new MyControlPanel(this);
DrawShape drawPanel = new DrawShape(this);

//Creates new form MyFrame
public MyFrame() {

    //setting the size, title and minimum size of the frame
    this.setSize(400, 400);
    this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
    this.setTitle("Shapes Program");

    initComponents();
    linkListeners();

    //setting the layout for the frame
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    //adding the components to the frame
    shape.add(square);
    shape.add(circle);
    shape.add(triangle);
    jMenuBar1.add(shape);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    //adding the panels to the frame 
    this.add(panel1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    this.add(drawPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}



//creating a new action listener for the shapes
public void linkListeners() {
    MyActionListener l = new MyActionListener();
    circle.addActionListener(l);
    square.addActionListener(l);
    triangle.addActionListener(l);

}

class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


        Object obj = e.getSource();

        //when square is selected, it is set to visable 
        //and outputs "Square Selected
        if ((JMenuItem) obj == square) {
            myShape = new Square();
            drawPanel.setIsSquare(true);
            System.out.println("Square Selected");

            //when circle is selected, it is set to visable 
            //and outputs "Circle Selected
        } else if ((JMenuItem) obj == circle) {
            myShape = new Circle();
            drawPanel.setIsCircle(true);
            System.out.println("Circle Selected");

            } 

            //when triangle is selected, it is set to visable 
            //and outputs "Triangle Selected
          else if ((JMenuItem) obj == triangle) {
            myShape = new Triangle();
            drawPanel.setIsTriangle(true);
            System.out.println("Triangle Selected");

        }
    }
}

public DrawShape getDrawPanel() {
    return drawPanel;

}

public MyShape getMyShape() {
    return myShape;
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MyFrame().setVisible(true);
            DecimalFormat oneDigit = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0");

        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Circle:

```
package MyShape;

/**
*
* @
*/
public class Circle extends MyShape {


@Override
public double computeArea(int length) {
    return length*length*Math.PI;
}


@Override
public double computeBLength(int length) {
    return 2*length*Math.PI;
}

}
```

Square:

```
package MyShape;

/**
*
* @
*/
public class Square extends MyShape {

@Override
public double computeArea(int length) {
  return length*length;
}

@Override
public double computeBLength(int length) {
   return 4*length;
}

}
```

Triangle:

```
package MyShape;

/**
*
* @
*/
public class Triangle extends MyShape {

@Override
public double computeArea(int length) {
    return length * 2 + Math.sqrt (2 * length * length);
}

@Override
public double computeBLength(int length) {
    return length * length / 2;
}

}
```

Comment: Rather than showing your entire code base, consider simplifying your problem to only show the relevant information. This enables the people who are trying to help you to identify your problem more quickly, and you may even solve your problem as you simplify.

Comment: Please sort out the code formatting and perhaps reduce all this code to a smaller example that people might actually have the time to study.

Comment: I don't see any question there. What's the problem, exactly?

Comment: Sorry, I'm look for some tips on where I would implement a user defined exception in either the jFrame or the two jPanels.  I want to throw the exception when the frame is resized to smaller than the items on the drawPanel. I will reduce the code once I get to a desktop. Thanks